# Aggregate in multiple columns

Tags: r

I've multiple stations (+1000) with more than 50 years to work on it, so I configured my df with the stations on the columns and dates on rows as the example.
Now I need to make summations of my parameter for each year in each column of data, but also i must know how many fields with no NA it counted to give me a specific value for each year in each station.
I hope you guys can help me, and sorry about the syntax and language.

```
year<-c(rep(2000,12),rep(2001,12),rep(2002,12), rep(2003,12))
data <- data.frame( year, month=rep(1:12,4),est1=rnorm(12*4,2,1),est2=rnorm(12*4,2,1),est3=rnorm(12*4,2,1))
data[3,3]<-NA
```

Comment: A fairly-common question, did you search on SO before asking the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sums:

```
> apply(data[,-(1:2)], 2, tapply, data$year, sum, na.rm=T)
         est1     est2     est3
2000 23.46997 21.36984 28.24381
2001 27.32517 28.84098 24.11784
2002 23.41737 25.47548 23.82606
2003 24.63551 24.51148 28.17723
```

Non NA's:

```
> apply(!is.na(data[,-(1:2)]), 2, tapply, data$year, sum)
     est1 est2 est3
2000   11   12   12
2001   12   12   12
2002   12   12   12
2003   12   12   12
```

And a version without `apply` (see @r2evans comment below):

```
sapply(data[,-(1:2)], tapply, data$year, sum, na.rm=T)

sapply(data.frame(!is.na(data[,3:5])), tapply, data$year, sum)
```

Comment: Don't use `apply` with `data.frame`s, it's bad practice and will break if there's a non-`numeric` column.

Comment: OK, I added a `sapply`-version. That's ugly.. :)

Comment: This is just an aggregate operation isn't it? `aggregate(data[c("est1","est2","est3")], data["year"], FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: To answer your last question I did a lot searching. There are some things that I cant understand. Why are we using data[,-(1:2)] then 2?

Comment: We don't want to sum years or months, that's why we use `data[,-(1:2)]`. And we want sum columns, that's why we use `2`. Type `?apply` and read it's help page. This sholud help.

Comment: whenever i make this with many row/col i cant watch the whole results, what can i do?, should i export it?

Comment: Yes, that's probably the best idea